# Performance differences between linq and classical method

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I want to know performance differences between below two code lines. Which one is faster?

1.

```
anyList = Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select((n, i) =>
          {
          if ((i >= 480 && i < 790) || (i >= 1050 && i < 1170)
              return 0;
          else if ((i >= 790 && i < 1050)
              return 1;                                       
          else
              return 2;
          }).ToList();
```

2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i++)
{
    if ((i >= 480 && i < 790) || (i >= 1050 && i < 1170)
        anyLisy.Add(0);
    else if ((i >= 790 && i < 1050)
        anyLisy.Add(1);                                       
    else
        anyLisy.Add(2);
}
```

Which one is faster, which one has much more allocated memory?

Comment: From http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ _If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster_ **then race your horses.**

Comment: The loop version is faster because there is nothing at all working in the favor of the LINQ solution.

Comment: Also he said something along the lines of if two things are both fast enough then it doesn't matter which is faster.

Comment: @usr yes you are right. There is no advantage of linq.

Answer (score 2):

use [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.STOPWATCH%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) and make some benchmark something like this

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i++)
{
    if ((i >= 480 && i < 790) || (i >= 1050 && i < 1170))
        anyLisy.Add(0);
    else if (i >= 790 && i < 1050)
        anyLisy.Add(1);                                       
    else
        anyLisy.Add(2);
}
stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

Comment: I'd guess you want to abstract the thing you are timing into a function and run it many times. I'd imagine that one run will be quick enough to not be very noticeable (in fact I tested and get as output: `RunTime 00:00:00.00`). Also you are missing the close brackets off your two if conditionals.

Comment: I agree in this  will not be more significant to make a lot of tests as there is no huge computation  I copied  code of the OP :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you were just showing the concept of stopwatching and sorry for not noticing the code mistakes were from the original. I just copy and pasted your code and didn't think about the fact you probably did the same. :)